# Why do my application level logs disappear when executed in oozie?

Tags: java, apache-spark, log4j, cloudera, oozie

I'm using oozie in CDH5 environment.  I'm also using the oozie web-console.  I'm not able to see any of the logs from my application.  I can see hadoop logs, spark logs, etc; but I see no application specific logs.

In my application I've included src/main/resources/log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

In my oozie workflow I have java-actions and spark-actions.

It is also important to note that when I run my application from the command line I do see my application level logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oozie runs each Action in a different "launcher" job -- actually a YARN job with a single mapper *(see exceptions below)*.

Whenever you see an "external ID" in the form `job_000000000_0000` then you can reach the YARN logs for `application_000000_0000` *(yeah, "job" is the legacy naming convention from Hadoop 1, still used by JobHistory service, but YARN has another naming convention).*

Your application output is actually **dumped into the YARN logs for that Oozie "launcher"**

- your StdErr is dumped as-is and can be retrieved in the "stderr" section
- your StdOut is dumped with a prefix on each line *(that prefix is used by Oozie to manage its `<capture_output/>` trick for Shell and Pig actions)* at the end of the atrocely verbose "stdout" section
- and nothing gets into the "syslog" section AFAIK

Bottom line:

1. run `oozie job -info ******` to get the list of Actions and the corresponding "external IDs" for your Oozie workflow execution
2. for each `job_*****_**` legacy ID, run `yarn logs -applicationId application_*****_** | more` to skim the global YARN logs, then zoom on your specific app logs
3. now you can try to automate that thing... have fun           **`B-)`**

---

*Exceptions to the "launcher" Oozie job principle* -- the E-mail Action / Filesystem Action are just API calls executed directly from the Oozie server process; and the MapReduce Action spawns a regular YARN job with multiple Mappers and Reducers.

Comment: As a side note, if you want to ship your app. logs to a monitoring system, then you might start a Flume agent *(or a couple of agents for HA)*, and send directly your logs on the wire via the Log4J Flume appender. That would avoid the hassle of digging into the YARN logs *ex post*.

Comment: One other thing I'm seeing is that if the job-id for spark application is job_000000000_0000 then I need to get the logs for job_000000000_0001 to see the spark app logs...

Comment: Ah, that's because the Oozie "launcher" job starts the Spark **driver**, but then the driver starts another YARN job for its **executors** -- you must skim the first YARN log to extract the ID of the second YARN log. Same method for Sqoop or Hive or Pig actions, that also spawn dynamically their own YARN job(s) -- and Oozie has no obvious way to track these.