# Oozie Java Action output not showing on the console

Tags: java, cloudera, oozie

I want to store my Oozie Java action class output. I am using plain java code here. Oozie job is running succesfully, but the system.out.println statements are not showing from my Java program.

How to verify my output in this case.Please suggest.

Comment: the output will be there in your yarn application log.

Comment: For a slightly more elaborate answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855616/why-do-my-application-level-logs-disappear-when-executed-in-oozie/38856067

Comment: If the logs are important for monitoring purposes, then I strongly suggest that you use some Log4J plug-in to ship them automatically to, say, an ElasticSearch indexer, or a Flume agent that buffers its input(s) to HDFS (rolling appender) or whatever.