# Oozie workflow ends without error, but shell action doesn't do anything

Tags: bash, oozie

If you want to know how I solved it, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257926/copying-files-from-a-hdfs-directory-to-another-with-oozie-distcp-action/43307956#43307956).

My workflow looks like this.

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="${PROJECT_NAME}">
  <global>
    <job-tracker>${JOB_TRACKER}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${NAME_NODE}</name-node>
    <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
        <value>${QUEUE_NAME}</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>mapreduce.job.reduces</name>
        <value>${REDUCE_TASKS}</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>today_without_dash</name>
        <value>${today_without_dash}</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yesterday_with_dash</name>
        <value>${yesterday_with_dash}</value>
      </property>
    </configuration>
  </global>

  <start to="start_fair_usage"/>

  <action name="start_fair_usage">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
      <job-tracker>${JOB_TRACKER}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${NAME_NODE}</name-node>
      <exec>${copy_file}</exec>      
      <argument>${today_without_dash}</argument>
      <argument>${mta}</argument>
      <!-- <file>${path}#${start_fair_usage}</file> -->
      <file>${path}${copy_file}#${copy_file}</file>
      <capture-output/>
    </shell>
    <ok to="END"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
  </action>
```

copy_file.sh

```
# directories in comverse where sub mtr rcr files are kept
echo "directories"
dirs=(
    /user/comverse/data/${today_without_dash}_B
    )

# clear the hdfs directory of old files and copy new files from comverse
echo "remove old files "${mta}

hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash /apps/hive/warehouse/db.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin/file_${mta}/*

for i in $(hadoop fs -ls "${dirs[@]}" | egrep ${mta}.gz | awk -F " " '{print $8}')
do
    hadoop fs -cp $i /apps/hive/warehouse/db.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin/file_${mta}
    echo "copy file - "${i}
done

echo "end copy "${mta}" files"
```

`${today_without_dash}` comes from coordinator

```
<property>
  <name>today_without_dash</name>
  <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:nominalTime(),'yyyyMMdd')}</value>
</property>
```

There are no errors, but it does not work either and I don't understand why.

There are some files in this

```
/apps/hive/warehouse/db.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin/file_${mta}
```

directory, but they don't get deleted. Nothing gets copied there either. There are files in this directory.

```
/user/comverse/data/${today_without_dash}_B
```

`${mta}` is from `job.properties`. It's value is mta

`copy_file.sh` works when I start it through CLI, without OOZIE

EDIT 
I asked around and was told that this might happen because the files I try to copy are too big.

Comment: Did you inspect the YARN logs? That's where all your shell StdOut and StdErr messages are captured.See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855616/why-do-my-application-level-logs-disappear-when-executed-in-oozie/38856067#38856067 for details.

Comment: @I did. There wasn't anything helpfull there. I solved this already and left a link in the beginning.