# Why java action System.out disappear when executed in Oozie?

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I'm using oozie environment. After successfully completition of the job, I can't find System.out.println output in the oozie log. I googled for many hours and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855616/why-do-my-application-level-logs-disappear-when-executed-in-oozie)

but without result. From oozie web console i got the job id "0000011-180801114827014-oozie-oozi-W", then i tried to get more information about the job using the following command:

> oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie/ -info 0000011-180801114827014-oozie-oozi-W

[image]

then i get the externalId from action **JobCompleted** **"16546"** and i think the job id **180801114827014**. Finally i tried to get log from java action using the following command:

> yarn logs -applicationId application_180801114827014_16546
>   [image]

Where I'm doing wrong? Any suggestion?

**Edit**

I check if log aggregation was enaled and seems that it is enabled
[image]

Then, where I'm a doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I can say from experience that stdout is not removed from any YARN action, however, the encouraged way to log information in your applications is using Log4j which goes to syslog, not stdout (or stderr).

However, as your terminal says, YARN log aggregation needs enabled / completed for you to see the logs from the `yarn logs` command

And if that command doesn't work otherwise, go to the Oozie UI, to the job action, or directly to the YARN UI and search for the action, then find the logs link from there

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm new about oozie/yarn and I' working on a legacy job full of System.out. My doubt was that the job id 180801 it was wrong...

Comment: Well, to see the output from your job, you need to enable log aggregation, as I mentioned